# Add new users as members to GCP Cloud Identity Group using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have the **gcp-organization-admins** Cloud Identity User Group to which I want to add a new user *user-01@example.com* as a Member using Terraform.

Getting error - **Error creating GroupMembership: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404.
The requested URL `/v1beta1/gcp-organization-admins@example.com/memberships?alt=json` was not found on this server.**
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this please.

fyi...Just as a test, I was able to create new Cloud Identity user groups and added some test users into it without any problems using Terraform module https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-group

```
#=====================
# terraform.tfvars
#=====================
org_admin_user = ["user-01@example.com"]
org_admin_group = "gcp-organization-admins@example.com"

#=========================================================
# add-member.tf (adds user to google group as a member)
#=========================================================
resource "google_cloud_identity_group_membership" "user-01" {
  for_each = toset(var.org_admin_user)
  provider = google-beta
  group = var.org_admin_group
  preferred_member_key {
    id = each.key
  }
  roles {
    name = "MEMBER"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, does the group exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can see it on the console (IAM > User Groups). I am also able to manually add users to this user group .

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem. Turns out that Terraform wants the GCP Group "name" and not the email address.

So the group attribute of the **google_cloud_identity_group_membership** resource block should look something like "**groups/23097432uwhwiyo**" and **not** "gcp-organization-admins@example.com"

You can look up the group "name" with the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud identity groups describe "gcp-organization-admins@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might to be the same issue as documented here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7616

A comment in that bug mentions the following:

```
I can work around the above issue by switching the order of the two roles in the resource, i.e.

From

  roles { name = "MANAGER" }
  roles { name = "MEMBER" }
to

  roles { name = "MEMBER" }
  roles { name = "MANAGER" }
```

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7616#issuecomment-742779169

Comment: Thanks Sam for your reply. As I am just adding a single MEMBER and not both MEMBER, MANAGER I cannot flip the order. I have also tried adding a MANAGER (for the purpose of testing) and switched the order but the error remains.

Comment: I do recommend making a comment in that issue or opening a new issue in the github repo. Sorry it didn't solve it for you yet